# Build a rest wrapper which accepts any kind of request

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jersey

I want to build a rest wrapper in a spring boot application which accepts any kind of request (API call). Lets assume I have two API calls /employee/123 (GET method) /dept/123 (PUT method). Now When I hit these two requests from postman client, my wrapper should accepts these two types of requests.

I have tried this with Filter and Interceptor. But those didn't work for me. Can any one please explain how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear what's your problem. Is this what you're looking for?

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/employee/{id}")
    public String getEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
       ....
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/dept/{id}")
    public String putDept(@PathVariable int id) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Or you want an API proxy? So, perhaps, it makes sense to look at Zuul or any similar project?

Comment: Thank you Kami. I am looking for a API proxy. As you mentioned, I'll try with zuul.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to accepts any kind of request like POST,GET,DELETE or PUT the dont mention the method of `RequestMethod` in `@RequestMapping`  and if you want to do different operation depends on Request method   then use `HttpServletRequest` for getting ReuestMethod 
eg.

```
@RequestMapping({ "/employee/{id}", "/dept/{id}" })
    public @ResponseBody String demo(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

        if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
            return "POST MEhod";
        } else if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
            return "GET Method";
        } else if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")) {
            return "PUT Method";
        } else {
            return "DELETE Method";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking same kind of thing. I'll try this.